# The pronoun of the word "data"

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns

I wrote:

> Web data extraction is the process of seeking and finding **data** on the Web, then extracting **them/it** from Web sources, and transforming **them/it** into structured data

I know "data" is plural but it is uncountable, so is its pronoun "them" or "it"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It.** Even uncountable nouns take singular pronouns provided that they are singular. Here are some examples:

> **Water** is essential to life; **it** is necessary for many biological processes to take place.
>
> I have collected **evidence** regarding the crime, but **it** may not be admissible in court.

NOTE - As pointed out by @sumelic, "Data" is treated by some as a plural noun. Should you decide in favor of this usage, use plural pronouns such as "them" and not "it."

Comment: The issue is that some people treat "data" as a plural noun. So figuring out if "provided that they are singular" applies is the problem here

Comment: @sumelic when I said "provided that they are singular," I was differentiating my examples from when uncountable nouns *actually take the plural.* For instance, you might say, "these waters are hard to navigate." In that case, "these waters" would be referred to as "they." However, if there is no "s" at the end of the noun making it plural, than it is singular and is referred to with singular pronouns. (Barring irregular plurals such as "cacti")

Comment: "data" can be an irregular plural like "cacti". Some people say "these data are".

Comment: In my experience in the (U.S.) tech sector, the ratio of people who treat data as singular to those who treat it as plural is over 100:1.  Personally, I don't care as long as you are consistent about it.

Comment: @sumelic I didn't know about that usage of "data," but from looking it up it does seem to be possible to use it as a plural. In that case, however, it is no longer an uncountable noun and my answer does not apply. As Andrew said, "data" is much more commonly used as a mass noun than as a count noun, but if you would rather use it as a count noun, that's fine; use "them" instead. —And I agree with Andrew's comment concerning consistency.

Comment: English is renowned as an 'adoptive parent' of words from all over the world. 'Data' is one such adoptee which, originally (and until quite recently), was only the plural of the adopted Latin word 'datum', and did not even have its own dictionary entry. Today, however, 'datum' and 'data' can be regarded independently. 'Data' can be treated as a plural, or (particularly in computing) as a singular. The original singular 'datum' is still used, particularly in geography and surveying, and in mathematics it has even developed a new plural 'datums'.

Comment: @WarrenHam That's so like English to mess up inflections from other languages while attempting to use the "authentic" forms—just look at the incorrect plural of "octopus": "octopi." In reality, the correct plural of the original Greek word is "octopodes."